# I am trying to invoke rest API using Java transformation getting compile error as cannot find symbol set Requestmethod

Tags: java, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

Below are the java packages and code written.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;


try{
    URL url=new  URL("https://dit2--abc.com");
    HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",access_token);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
    String requestBody ="{\"Id\":\"Id\", \"OwnerId\":\"OwnerId\"}";
    try(OutputStream os =conn.getOutputStream()){
        byte[] input=requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
        os.write(input,0,input.length);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
   
//    String line;

    StringBuffer response= new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    if (conn.getResponseCode() ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!= null){
        response.append(line);
      }
fi= response.toString().substring(response.toString().length() -10);
}
    reader.close();
}catch(Exception e){
logInfo("Error");
fi =e.toString();
}
```

The above code is updated code , after compiling no errors but the workflow keeps on running does not end, as if the code is running in loop.

Kindly once check this code.

Comment: Where is your call to `connect` to actually get the data?

Comment: updated full code in the question

Comment: It will not compile, if not for the various typos, at least for a missing declaration of `responseOut`

Comment: please take care of proper code formatting. I suggest that you use the three backticks ("`") at begin and end of your source code snippet  instead of the indenting. This makes copy-paste a lot easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to go through the errors one by one, even for errors that are not shown on your screenshots:

Line 200: upper/lowercase problem with the constructor `Url()`, should be `URL url = new URL("https://ditabc.com");`

Line 210: you need to declare the Exception class for e, so `} catch (java.io.IOException e) {` would be correct here.

Line 213: you cannot do `os.flush();` here, as `os` is only known inside the try-with-resources block above. `os` also will automatically be closed when that try-with-resources block is finished, so flush should not be necessary at all.

Line 217: full of typos, should be `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));`

Line 218: you cannot compare the `StringBuffer response` that has not even be read out with an integer constant. Should be `if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {`

Line 223: you don't have a `writer` to close, just drop this line.

Line 225: this problem is caused by the `if (response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){` in line 218. It is not properly closed. You have messed up the indenting a bit so you cannot easily see it, but after the `fi= response.toString().substring(response.toString().length() -10);` in line 222 there is a `}` missing.

All errors after line 225 are in generated code, so they probably come from the missing `}` that I already mentioned.

You are not handling all exceptions similar, are you sure this is the correct way?
I'm quite sure that the inner try-with-resources block in the lines 207 to 212 will cause trouble: if you cannot write out the request successfully, it does not make sense to try to read the response afterwards. I would simply get the `os` without an extra try-catch block, and close it instead of the `writer` in line 223.

Also you are missing an important step: you do not connect.
Add a `conn.connect()` before you do the `OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()`.

The code you pasted is also missing several `import` statements, these will miss to make it compile:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
```

(I saw a section in the code where the code generator would insert imports, and in a previous version of your question you had some of them in an extra piece of code. You will need to import the above classes somehow, but not in one piece with your own code snippet.)

As a general advice: don't try to learn Java with that tool, it is really hard to work with a development environment that generates code for you and only provides editors without syntax highlighting etc. (I know that from experience with similar tools.)

UPDATE: in the try-with-resources block at line 214 you first miss one of the above imports (you imported `java.io.OutputStreamReader`, but it has to be `java.io.OutputStream`) and the keyword `new` is disturbing here, please remove it.

Comment: Sorry I have mistyped it, corrected. however the issue is with the set RequestMethod it is giving as symbol not found

Comment: I extended my answer as your original question still contains the typos and future readers will maybe benefit from the more complete answer.

Comment: updated my answer for your updated code - even by hand I spotted several typos in your code. Did you copy this by hand or use copy-paste? Try to be more careful with code, the compiler is really picky with correct syntax and upper/lower-case. Will prevent headaches ;)

Comment: I am new to java. i am trying to acheive this in informatica powercentre. i have 2 fields id and owner id which iam passing as body and a acccess token. when i hit the rest api i get resposnse success or error . i capture this in one output port.  trying it for first time. if you can help to correct code it will be helpful.

Comment: I have to admit that I on the other hand don't have any experience with Informatica Powercenter, but with similar tools. Question for me is: where does the input come from? where does the result go to? Is this something declared outside your code? What are the available variables? (I suppose that a huge bunch of Java code is generated from your whole project where your snippet is just a tiny piece that is placed into the whole code generated from the system.)

Comment: we just get three values two fields "Id" and Ownerid (sending as json body as in code)and one is token which we use here for authorization as in code. we just need to get whether it is sucess or failure response , can be captured in any variable or string. there is nothing out of the code only we get some values from source which i can manage to replace in the code. and output response we capture anywhere. i just want in code to hit the url and send the requestbody.

Comment: ok, but then my suggestions in the answer should be sufficient. Did you try any of them?

Comment: Doing line by line compiling .. can you edit and declare response variable if I have not declared.. I need to capture response once the body gets posted..we get success codes like 200, 201 with some string. Response as well. While I compile I get try , catch not properly declared . Is catch and try properly declared.

Comment: Hi Cyberbrain. i have attached full code where you can also find the actual code in that. line and fi are two output ports fi is the final response.  attached the compile errors if you copy paste notepad you can find the error line numbers. Any help truly appreciate .

Comment: I updated my answer again. You want to receive the last 10 characters of the response as output, is this correct?

Comment: okay thanks, for success we received codes like 200,201 so thats the reason printing 10 characters, if needed i can increase from my end.

Comment: I have updated the latest code with the corrections , getting couple of errors. added a sample java code which follows same process. in sample they used GET instead of POST method.

Comment: If you are updating your code at the same time from my answer and from different sources, we are working against a moving target. Will be hard to hit. You didn't use all the includes I gave you while you also didn't update the error messages - e.g. there simply is no `catch(e)` anymore in your code, but you didn't remove the screenshot of that error message.

Comment: I have not updated the code from different source , i just pasted a sample i got from google which is related to informatica since some of the declarations showing invalid in tool which might help you to help me. I have updated  the code and removed the error message. i currently got two compile errors. which uploaded image

Comment: I have updated the code compiled now no errors. however there is only one record placed with Id, ownerId and token from source, but job keeps on running

Comment: This would be another question on SO and I cannot help you on that because this will be an issue of your Informatica job. You could try to add a `conn.disconnect();` after the `reader.close();` but it's probably not solving the problem. Would highly appreciate if you at least upvote my answer, if you don't want to accept it.

Comment: Truly appreciate your patience and efforts for taking time  and answering this.  Need to research more on the code , anything you found on this can share as well. Thanks  lot..

Comment: Hi . when i use Id and ownerid access token actual values i am able to send request but when i use field names which i get from source it gives 500 error response. is it the format or any other which is causing this?

Comment: First this is another question and second you should look up the docs of the server side how to use it properly. HTTP status 500 means "internal server error", so some "unexpected" error on the server occurred.

Comment: i was able to resolve this the tool could not take the request body as defined in the code  due to the escape sequences tool cannot read and not sending body. i have sent as json body(key value pairs from previous transformation itself so the request got posted .you have been big help in this. thank you.